# Make table-cell 100% width of parent

Tags: html, css

How would I make the table-cell 100% width of the parent.

It works perfectly fine when the text is long enough to reach the full width of the element but when the text is not it doesn't want to center whilst using table-cell and vertical-align: middle;

```
Here is a fiddle:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7471/

Comment: everything looks fine to me on your fiddle. The green is going 100% the width of the parent container. Try different browsers

Comment: But the text inside is not centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

Here's a better solution using a flex-box:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7516/)

```
h4 {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
   }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, but this is not what I am after. I need the text to be centered in the box vertically and horizontally. I can't seem to get them both to work at the same time when the text does not run 100% of the width. Line-height is not a solution as well as some text is on 2 lines some on 1